# Is there a way to set default launcher app in AOSP without excluding other launchers

Tags: android, android-source, android.mk

I'm aware of `LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES` but I would like to set Launcher3 as my default launcher without overwriting another app I have installed.

So I want the app to exist on the system but not be set as default and `LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES` does not allow me todo that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the intent-filter's priority. This priority should be above 0, and less then the Provision' priority.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element#priority

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1">
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

The Provision(or SetupWizard) should has the top priority. It will be launched when the first boot. Once it finished, it will be disabled. Then the normal launcher will be launched.

So you can set the priority to override the Launcher3.

Comment: I wan't Launcher3 to override everything, how do I do that so the popup doesnt show up asking which home app?

Comment: You can set your laucher as perfered launcher programmatically by addPreferredActivityAsUser. It only can be called by system app. 
 https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java;l=6898?q=addPreferredActivityAsUser